# Printing Article and Author Name In Text from .bib

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

Is there a way to tell BibTeX/`natbib` to print the name of an article and the author's name in text?

For instance, where I would usually use `\citep{cite-key}` to deliver the in-text citation `(<Author Last Name> <Publication Year>)`, is there a similar command to print the entire author and article name? I'm looking for something that if I were to type something like `\printarticle{cite-key}` it would deliver `<Full Author Name>, "Article Title"` in-text in that location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this cannot be done by `natbib` alone (unless very heavy modifications). However, this can be done very simply in `biblatex` or by using `usebib`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{usebib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {The Alpha Paper},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibinput{\jobname}

\newcommand{\printarticle}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}, ``\usebibentry{#1}{title}''}

\begin{document}

\printarticle{A01}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]